# Recombining large chunked zip download in GO

Tags: http, go, goroutine, appendfile, range-header

I am downloading a large .zip file in parallel with Accept-Ranges and Goroutines. The application sends multiple requests to download 10MB chunks of a zip file from a URL using its Range header.

The requests get split up into different ranges as separate Goroutines and the data obtained is written into temp files. The files are named 1, 2, 3....

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    url := "https://path/to/large/zip/file/zipfile.zip"
    res, _ := http.Head(url)
    maps := res.Header
    length, _ := strconv.Atoi(maps["Content-Length"][0]) // Get the content length from the header request
    chunks := (length / (1024 * 1024 * 10)) + 1

    // startByte and endByte determines the positions of the chunk that should be downloaded
    var startByte = 0
    var endByte = (1024 * 1024 * 10) - 1
    //body := make([][]byte, chunks)
    body := make([]io.ReadCloser, chunks)

    for i := 0; i < chunks; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(min int, max int, i int) {
            client := &http.Client {}
            req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
            rangeHeader := "bytes=" + strconv.Itoa(min) +"-" + strconv.Itoa(max)
            fmt.Println(rangeHeader)
            req.Header.Add("Range", rangeHeader)

            resp,_ := client.Do(req)
            defer resp.Body.Close()

            reader, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
            body[i] = resp.Body
            ioutil.WriteFile(strconv.Itoa(i), reader, 777) // Write to the file i as a byte array

            wg.Done()
        }(startByte, endByte, i)

        startByte = endByte + 1
        endByte += 1024 * 1024 * 10
    }
    wg.Wait()

    filepath := "zipfile.zip"
    // Create the file
    _, err := os.Create(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    file, _ := os.OpenFile(filepath, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, os.ModeAppend)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }


    for j := 0; j < chunks; j++ {
        newFileChunk, err := os.Open(strconv.Itoa(j))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer newFileChunk.Close()

        chunkInfo, err := newFileChunk.Stat()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        var chunkSize int64 = chunkInfo.Size()
        chunkBufferBytes := make([]byte, chunkSize)

        // read into chunkBufferBytes
        reader := bufio.NewReader(newFileChunk)
        _, err = reader.Read(chunkBufferBytes)
        file.Write(chunkBufferBytes)
        file.Sync() //flush to disk
        chunkBufferBytes = nil // reset or empty our buffer
    }

    //Verify file size
    filestats, err := file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    actualFilesize := filestats.Size()
    if actualFilesize != int64(length) {
        log.Fatal("Actual Size: ", actualFilesize, " Expected: ", length)
        return
    }

    file.Close()
}
```

After all the files are downloaded, I try to recombine them into one .zip file. However, when the files are put together, I can't unzip the final file, as it appears to be corrupted.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong, or if there's a better approach to this. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Below is what gets logged to the console

```
bytes=0-10485759
bytes=10485760-20971519
2018/12/04 11:21:28 Actual Size: 16877828 Expected: 16877827
```

Comment: You are not accounting for the case where the file size is a multiple of 10MB; you'd be requesting one extra chunk. Also, if the file size is not a multiple of 10MB, the last chunk will be shorter, and you are not accounting for that either. You should also get rid of that `body` slice. Holding on to closed ReadClosers isn't useful.

Comment: you're ignoring a ton of errors, you could use a helper like this: `func panicIfErr(err error) { if err != nil { panic(err) } }` and then just `panicIfErr(err)` only for main functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your range requests

the lines

```
   resp,_ := client.Do(req)
   defer resp.Body.Close()
```

are reported by `go vet` as the err isn't checked.  If you check the response code in the last chunk it is 416 - which is an incorrect range used, alter to this

```
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if resp.StatusCode == 416 {
    fmt.Println("incorrect range")
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

I also altered the loop variable to `for i := 0; i < chunks-1; i++ {`
and altered the section after the go routine

```
startByte = endByte + 1
endByte += 1024 * 1024 * 10
if startByte >= length {
    break
}
for endByte >= length {
    endByte = endByte - 1
}
```

and altered the j loop variable in a similar way

These changes seemed to work for me but I don't have suitable test data to really check